# Converting special characters in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a built in way to convert special characters in rails from ASCII to html?

I saw 'htmlentities' but saw it is form a while back and wondered if there was anything more generic lately?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for CGI.unescape? Give an example of the special characters you want to convert.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we want to output *Renée Zellweger*... and we want to write...

```
    flash[:notice] = 'Renée Zellweger was successfully created.'
```

without having to worry about writing *`&eacute;`*...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

use Iconv class conv method to convert special character

Iconv.conv('ISO-8859-9', 'utf-8', 'Renée Zellweger was successfully created.')